# Changing (back to default) font in ipython notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I used the following code to change the font of my notebook:

```
<style>
div.text_cell_render {
font-family: "Times New Roman", serif, serif;
}
</style>
```

But, didnt like the outcome. I tried to change it back by:

```
<style>
div.text_cell_render {
font-family: "Arial", serif;
}
</style>
```

But this does not working. is it becuase Arial is not a serif? I tried different combinations but non worked...

Comment: Can you try refreshing the page without cache (CTRL+F5 in most browsers on Windows)?

Comment: Didn't help. The styling command is valid?